# How to connect to MAMP MySQL Server using DataGrip

Tags: mysql, datagrip

DataGrip doesn't connect to my local MySQL server that comes with MAMP Pro server. However, when I try connecting with PHP or the `mysql` command, it works perfectly. Can anyone help?

Comment: Datagrip needs to be configured in order to know which server you want to talk to and what db, etc. See:
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/help/getting-started-with-datagrip.html#define_database
What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Of course, its pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: So does that mean you don't need an answer any more? Or are you being ironic? I wasn't trying to RTFM* you, just asking what you had tried already that hadn't worked. That's usually much more productive in terms of generating answers.
RTFM: https://xkcd.com/293/

Comment: not at all... anyway i found a solution. i changed the value of bind-ip-address to 0.0.0.0 in my.cnf and it worked... thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to edit my.cnf (You must edit the template here: `Mamp PRO -> File -> Edit Template -> MySQL my.cnf`)

I commented out `MAMP_bind-address_MAMP` and added a new line `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` to allow incoming connections from all IPs.

```
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
# MAMP_bind-address_MAMP
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Hope it helps anyone who has the same problem.

Comment: Jesse, don't forget to accept your own answer. You deserve the credit for figuring it out. And it can help others have a bit more confidence in your own response as time goes along.

Answer (score 9):

MAMP Pro -> Mysql Tab -> Check "Allow network access to Mysql" -> Save -> Profit!

Comment: Is it possible to do this without Pro?